# Why does keras return the same output for all inputs?

Tags: python, keras

I am building a regression model that is supposed to take 100 data points and output 18 data points. The inputs are x, y coordinates of image, and outputs are latitude and longitude objects detected (will be zero if no object is detected). For some reason when I train the model I get the same output for every input. The keras model code is as below:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, input_shape=(2,), activation='softmax'))  
model.add(Dense(2, input_shape=(16,), activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(2, activation='linear'))
```

Comment: did you check the outputs of the layer activations? it could be that your activations in one or several of the layers are saturated and always return the same values because they are not actually calibrated well to the inputs (imagine you always get large positive values out of the second layer, then feeding them through the sigmoid activation will result in approx. 1 always). do you preprocess your data? i.e. normalize, etc?

Comment: In which coordinate system do you want the longitude/latitude ?

Comment: I want to put longitude in x axis and latitude in y axis!